# Seaborn Heatmap Subplots - keep axis ratio consistent

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

If I have the following code:

```
import seaborn 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")
f,(ax1,ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(1,3,sharey=True)
g1 = sns.heatmap(flights,cmap="YlGnBu",cbar=False,ax=ax1)
g1.set_ylabel('')
g1.set_xlabel('')
g2 = sns.heatmap(flights,cmap="YlGnBu",cbar=False,ax=ax2)
g2.set_ylabel('')
g2.set_xlabel('')
g3 = sns.heatmap(flights,cmap="YlGnBu",ax=ax3)
g3.set_ylabel('')
g3.set_xlabel('')
```

Which outputs the following -
[image]

How can I adjust the subplots so that the g3 axis is the same width as the g1,g2 axis. Since I have not added the color bar to the first two axis', seaborn shrinks the third axis down to make the entire figure consistent. This is understandable.

I want this:

[image]

Perhaps I need to make a 4 panel subplot with the fourth panel only containing the colorbar?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A way to go is indeed to create 4 axes, where the fourth axes will contain the colorbar. You can use the `cbar_ax` argument to tell the heatmap in which axes to plot the colorbar. In order to create the axes with some good proportions, you can use the `gridspec_kw` argument to `subplots`. The problem is then that the axes would share the y scaling with the colorbar, so we need to turn sharey off and manually share the first three axes by using `ax1.get_shared_y_axes().join(ax2,ax3)`. This in turn will create unwanted axis labels, which need to be turned off.

```
import seaborn  as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")
f,(ax1,ax2,ax3, axcb) = plt.subplots(1,4, 
            gridspec_kw={'width_ratios':[1,1,1,0.08]})
ax1.get_shared_y_axes().join(ax2,ax3)
g1 = sns.heatmap(flights,cmap="YlGnBu",cbar=False,ax=ax1)
g1.set_ylabel('')
g1.set_xlabel('')
g2 = sns.heatmap(flights,cmap="YlGnBu",cbar=False,ax=ax2)
g2.set_ylabel('')
g2.set_xlabel('')
g2.set_yticks([])
g3 = sns.heatmap(flights,cmap="YlGnBu",ax=ax3, cbar_ax=axcb)
g3.set_ylabel('')
g3.set_xlabel('')
g3.set_yticks([])

# may be needed to rotate the ticklabels correctly:
for ax in [g1,g2,g3]:
    tl = ax.get_xticklabels()
    ax.set_xticklabels(tl, rotation=90)
    tly = ax.get_yticklabels()
    ax.set_yticklabels(tly, rotation=0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Can you tell me one last thing? Which method of axcb could be used to set the label? axcb.set_label() does not seem to do anything.

Comment: I think you mean `axcb.set_ylabel("Some label")`?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest FYI, this method is no longer supposed to be used, [since 3.6.0 per the API changelog](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.6.0.html#groupers-from-get-shared-x-axes-get-shared-y-axes-will-be-immutable)
"`Groupers from get_shared_x_axes / get_shared_y_axes will be immutable`"
... And now I'm not sure how to get the same result in the future.

Comment: Setting `subplots(... , sharey=True) definitely doesn't provide the same results, and now I'm not sure how to get the same result in the future, when the shared groupers become immutable.

Comment: I think the answer should be updated now. I get `AttributeError: 'GrouperView' object has no attribute 'join'` for this line `ax1.get_shared_y_axes().join(ax2,ax3)`