# AttributeError: 'GrouperView' object has no attribute 'join'

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn, heatmap, attributeerror

I'm trying to reproduce this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42712772/10452700) but getting the following error:

> AttributeError: 'GrouperView' object has no attribute 'join'

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[283], line 7
      4 flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")
      5 f,(ax1,ax2,ax3, axcb) = plt.subplots(1,4, 
      6             gridspec_kw={'width_ratios':[1,1,1,0.08]})
----> 7 ax1.get_shared_y_axes().join(ax2,ax3)
      8 g1 = sns.heatmap(flights,cmap="YlGnBu",cbar=False,ax=ax1)
      9 g1.set_ylabel('')

AttributeError: 'GrouperView' object has no attribute 'join'
```

Also, [seaborn](/questions/tagged/seaborn) version is as below:

```py
print(sns.__version__) #0.13.0
import matplotlib
print('matplotlib: {}'.format(matplotlib.__version__) #matplotlib: 3.8.1)
```

I checked some working around but couldn't solve the problem in the plot since there is no real string `ax2,ax3` when I print :

- [I am getting an error as list object has no attribute 'join'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53832607/10452700)

Even I downgraded seaborn but didn't solve the problem based on this [thread](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/discussions/3521)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As proposed in the [3.6 API changes](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.6.0.html#groupers-from-get-shared-x-axes-get-shared-y-axes-will-be-immutable), (and repeated in the [3.8 API changes](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.8.0.html#groupers-from-get-shared-x-axes-get-shared-y-axes-are-immutable)), use [`Axes.sharey`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.sharey.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.sharey).

```
ax1.sharey(ax2)
ax2.sharey(ax3)
```

Since an `Axes` can only `sharey` with one other `Axes`, I'm unaware of an alternative that lets `ax1` share with both `ax2` and `ax3` in one step.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution : Please downgrade matplotlib to 3.7 or 3.6**

Your error has nothing to do with **seaborn**.

You are getting this error because of **matplotlib**:

When I upgrade my matplotlib to `3.8.1`.  I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'GrouperView' object has no attribute 'join'
```

Also I am getting deprecation warning in matplotlib 3.6

**MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The join function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.6 and will be removed two minor releases later.**

I was able to reproduce the graph in matplotlib 3.6 and 3.7

Code goes here:

```
import seaborn  as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")
f,(ax1,ax2,ax3, axcb) = plt.subplots(1,4, 
            gridspec_kw={'width_ratios':[1,1,1,0.08]})
ax1.get_shared_y_axes().join(ax2,ax3)
g1 = sns.heatmap(flights,cmap="YlGnBu",cbar=False,ax=ax1)
g1.set_ylabel('')
g1.set_xlabel('')
g2 = sns.heatmap(flights,cmap="YlGnBu",cbar=False,ax=ax2)
g2.set_ylabel('')
g2.set_xlabel('')
g2.set_yticks([])
g3 = sns.heatmap(flights,cmap="YlGnBu",ax=ax3, cbar_ax=axcb)
g3.set_ylabel('')
g3.set_xlabel('')
g3.set_yticks([])

# may be needed to rotate the ticklabels correctly:
for ax in [g1,g2,g3]:
    tl = ax.get_xticklabels()
    ax.set_xticklabels(tl, rotation=90)
    tly = ax.get_yticklabels()
    ax.set_yticklabels(tly, rotation=0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Also had the same issue as when sharing axes via .sharey it is not possible to auto-zoom to see all datapoints, as with .join previously.